# SlowCheetah - VS 2013 not showing up even if supported

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I try to make SlowCheetah work, but when I open the VSIX File, I get just th VS 2010 as Selection.

If I check the File, I definitely see:

```
  <VisualStudio Version="12.0">
    <Edition>Ultimate</Edition>
    <Edition>Premium</Edition>
    <Edition>Pro</Edition>
  </VisualStudio>
</SupportedProducts>
```

And we have Premium 2013.

Is there anything else I need to be aware of?

Comment: Vs 2013 has not offred a lot of things perhaps thats is why see this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386063.aspx

Comment: I'm nut sure what you mean. Isn't that more of a problem about the VSIX File or my missunderstanding?